# Dell studio xps 1647 BIOS update

Tags: dell, bios

Short question. Does anybody managed to update BIOS on Dell studio xps 1647 from Ubuntu? 
I have A01 and want to update to A11. I read a lot of stuff on the web and around how to do this and failed. Freedos approach finished with a problem of running exe file (with BIOS update from dell website) as a file that can't be run in a dos mode (or sth similar).

Answer (score 0):

I did a bios upgrade when i first got my 1640; I did not do it on ubuntu; instead I immediately did it on Win 7 that came pre-installed. I am not sure though whether I had dual boot at the time or not.

My suggestion is that you do the upgrade from Windows; I guess its safer. If you don't have Windows installed I'd recommend you install a genuine one if you have it. 
In either case, find the right bios by using the service tag of your laptop; use this page: https://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriversHome/NeedProductSelection
Follow the "Installation Instructions" as written on the bios upgrade page.

Otherwise I suggest you seek help from a computer specialist.

Warning: a bios upgrade, if failed, can break your computer!

Disclaimer: this is just suggestions not guidance; I hold no responsibility for any problems or failures!

All the best

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Inspiron 7520 and had similar problems; basically the executable for the upgrade downloaded from the Dell site has to be run in a Windows 7 environment. If your machine is dual-boot with a Windows 7 option that is no problem, but if like me you have removed Windows entirely there are still ways to do the upgrade.

Check out my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100945/how-do-i-update-the-bios-of-a-dell-laptop). The key is to boot you computer into a Windows 7 command line mode, which can be done using a Windows 7 Repair Disk (*not* installation media!). If you have the executable on a USB drive it is then trivial to run it.

It is possible to make a small USB drive into a bootable Windows 7 Repair drive if you do not have a CD drive.

I obtained my Windows 7 Repair Disk by installing a copy of Win7 on a VirtualBox VM, but you can download them from the web, or find a friend with a Win7 machine to make one for you.