# I need to change out my Bios in my Asus g75vw

Tags: bios, version-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the BIOS of a Dell laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100945/how-do-i-update-the-bios-of-a-dell-laptop)

I need to upgrade my bios to eliminate some issue i'm haveing with my system. 
     I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus g75vw ( No Duel Boot ) after a clean install.

I have downloaded bios version 222 to replace the existing 210 that it is currently using.
My question is how do I go about doing this?

I am very new to linux (3 days) and could really use some help.

Thank you

Comment: 'some issue'. And this issue can not be solved?

Comment: As shown by @blvbeer this is the topic to follow and esp. Bobble's answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100945/how-do-i-update-the-bios-of-a-dell-laptop It is a general answer not specifically for DELL and works for other brands too.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy you don't do this with linux, because the most flash-tools just run on Windows (as far as i know). You should get the tools at the asus website.
They mustly also run under some dos-like live-systems.

Comment: There was a similar question about upgrading the BIOS on dell laptop, take a look at it [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100945/how-do-i-update-the-bios-of-a-dell-laptop/100955#100955). The procedure described there (especially the answer by [Bobble](http://askubuntu.com/users/68496/bobble)) could come in handy