# Dell Dimension New RAM Installation Problems

Tags: installation, dell, ram, bios

I Have tried pretty much everything to get this RAM (2x1GB PC2 5300/5400 DDR2 667MHz) to work. I am 99.9 percent sure it is compatible with my Dell Dimension C521. I know all the slots are working because my old RAM (2x512MB DDR2) works perfectly fine in all the slots (there are 4 slots). When I put in the New RAM and start up the computer my screen goes to sleep I hear 1 beep, 3 beeps, another 2 beeps and once again 2 more beeps (1-3-2-2). Then the fan goes on full blast and there is a green 1 and 3 indicator light that stays on. (Power button lights up green if you were wondering and mother board has the orange light as always). Either these BRAND NEW Sticks of RAM are shot or I need to update my BiOS which is almost impossible on Ubuntu, i cant figure it out. My current BiOS version is 1.1.4 but I am able to download version 1.1.11 I don't have access to a windows disk to run the EXE files either. Please Help ! and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Most of your question is unrelated to Ubuntu. The only thing I can find is the "How to update my BIOS?" question. If that's correct, please remove all the other parts as that's hardware related and off-topic here.

Comment: Does this help? [How do I update the BIOS of a Dell laptop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/100945/88802)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing ram modules, you need to test each dimm seperately to make sure it works alone and if so then the problem lies in inserting two mismatched dimm's...  Preferably ram should be of the same type and speed to be 100% compatible...