# How to update BIOS on Lenovo ThinkBook in Ubuntu?

Tags: updates, lenovo, bios

I have a Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2 ITL laptop purchased without an OS. This laptop
is currently running Ubuntu 20.04. I have an .exe file with updated BIOS for
this laptop. However, there is no option to update the BIOS in the BIOS menu.
In addition, the boot menu does not see the flash drive with the .exe file.
Tell me how can I update the BIOS on my Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2 ITL in ubuntu
20.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lenovo B590 BIOS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617810/lenovo-b590-bios-upgrade)

Comment: Thank you. This post answered my question.