# Keyboard Randomly Stops Working (Lenovo IdeaPad Y700-15ISK)

Tags: boot, keyboard, video, bios

My Keyboard suddenly stopped working while watching youtube videos. The video stopped and the keyboard did not work anymore.
Nothing happened when I typed. Also other keys like adjusting volume, toggle backlights etc. didn't work.

I tried rebooting, but after restart it booted me into some kind of Windows-like boot screen or something. It had a blue background, a rectangular shaped light-grey frame and some texts in it. 
I remember that it had a recovery mode, BIOS and some else stuff mentioned there.

I powered off my laptop. After turning it back on all was good and looking fine.

Today I had the same issue again. Watching a Youtube video it again hanged like that and my keyboard went down. This time I tried to turn off rather than restart, but it just kept hang at turn off so I had to force unpower it anyway. Now I'm telling this here so it's working again, but I'm afraid that this issue could repeat.

My questions:

- What may cause this issue?
- How to prevent it repeating/fix it?

**EDIT**
The issue repeated the second time already today and I restarted it again. This menu showed up:
[image: The menu]
This seems to have something to do with my laptop and could be a part of it's ROM, I guess. However, IDK what exactly it is, why the keyboard stops working and all of this happens. I guess one solution would be to completely reinstall my operating system?
Oh, and a note about the videos - when this issues starts, the sound and image of the video seems to unsync. And than the sound gets stuck while video plays and vice versa. It's really weird, for sure.

**EDIT**
So after examining closer I noticed:

- This only happens in browser(Google Chrome) and so far only when watching YouTube videos. Haven't tried other videos or other browser, though.
- When this happens, my keyboard backlights turns off. The num lock light is on.

System specs:

- Lenovo IdeaPad Y700 laptop
- Ubuntu 16.10

**EDIT**

- This so far has only happened in Chrome, Chromium browsers(Firefox not tested) and in Skype(Linux alpha version). No other programs or even games have caused this issue for me this far.

**EDIT**

- It seems that this can happen during use of basicly any program. Yesterday I experienced this issue while making models in Blender 3D.

**EDIT**

- And I found something: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Y700-keyboard-issue/m-p/3455702#M149284 Now I'm wondering what's the Linux version of workaround. Or is it the same as on Windows?

**EDIT**

After request in a comment, here is the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`:
http://pastebin.com/4kv4ftT8

Comment: Well, the computer freeze lasts like 1 second, than it's normal, except that the keyboard doesn't work.
Oh, and that's not GRUB menu as GRUB menu has got a purple background for me aswell as smaller letters and fancier font. Oh, and it offers different options than the glitch screen. Unfourtunately, I can't show it as I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I had a bug that used %100 of CPU when watching youtube. This was overheating the laptop. Have you tried runing `top` in a console to see what is running when you watch videos?

Comment: Chrome, Xorg and Pulseaudio.

Comment: Oh, and compiz aswell:D

Comment: I am starting to get desperate of this issue. It happens more and more oftenly + there is no information about this on the network(or I don't know where to look for it).

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`

Comment: @user.dz Added the output;)

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, Just to give a picture to what I'm heading. When issues have unclear reasons or hard to debug  that seem related  to driver/hardware, it is good to follow bug reporting procedure for Linux kernel. So I would suggest, upgrading your BIOS ROM to last release (yours: `CDCN27WW`, there are two newer: `CDCN35WW` & `CDCN53WW`) see http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/IdeaPad-Y-Series-laptops/y700-15isk?tabName=Downloads&beta=false . If not solved try last mainstream kernel, see  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, to make sure that you understand to risk of upgrading the BIOS, please read the README/release-note file of each upgrade.

Comment: I just read your last linked reference to Lenovo forum, its solution is upgrade BIOS.  To answer your question,  If that worked for Windows, then it is expected to fix it for Linux too. Any running OS have to deal with same BIOS system.

Comment: OK! But how to update BIOS for Linux? It's hard to find any solutions around.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, That is a Win32 executable, Any FreeDOS based solution will NOT work, Same for Windows 7 64bit recovery CD. I could only point you to try Windows 7/8 32bit recovery CD, you can have it from Internet (Lenovo if you have license) or even ask someone else have Windows 7 installed to make one for you. (I expect you don't want install it just for BIOS update), same method explained in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/237742/26246

Comment: Looks complex. Hm... How high is the risk of bricking computer any way by doing BIOS update, by the way?

Also, if I install Windows in doal-boot alongside Ubuntu, does it make the BIOS update easier? And does it matter if it's licensed Windows :D?

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, Risk: max damage is that it need service repair to get BIOS chip reprogrammed, however the chance that this could happen is very very low. The only advice: avoid it if you have unstable electric supply and charge battery before update.  Complex, may be, but dual boot seems much work to me (as you need to  change partitions before and to fix grub boot after windows install) .  No it doesn't matter, many  have [the elephant](http://www.itworld.com/article/2759836/open-source-tools/illuminating-the-elephant-in-the-open-source-room.html) at house.

Comment: I have a plan to install Windows for a few applications(that I can't manage to run on Linux even via Wine after setting up as much .dlls as possibly can be needed) and thus I will do it dual-boot anyways(I also found how). However, would you suggest me to install the dual-boot windows first or updating BIOS first?

Comment: No preference, up to you.

Comment: I would say, first backup, second upgrade the BIOS from a bootable ISO _(to avoid the possibility of an error installing windows or resizing partitions)_, third: play hard with your keyboard on linux _(and maybe others)_...

Comment: So having a bootable windows USB is the best solution for the BIOS update, right?:D

Comment: @dgonzalez, this is just to notify you about AdriansNetlis comment for you.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, you could use `@` with username to notify him like I did in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, i always prefer _bootable iso_ options to update BIOS, i think that reduces points of failure and also is OS agnostic. PD: @user.dz thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Have Ubuntu 16.04 + latest (as of 2018-March-20) nvidia drivers (don't have laptop at hand - can't tell exact version).

Solved by selecting to use ONLY Discreet GPU (Nvidia only - no switching between Intel HD and Geforce).

So far solved all problems.

Comment: Selection must be made in BIOS. ( To access BIOS press F2 during boot)